# Proving $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \mu (A_n) \leq K \mu \left ( \cup_{n=1}^{+\infty} A_n \right )$ under some conditions on $A_n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ a measure space and $A_n$ a sequence of measurable sets such that each point of the space belongs to at most $K$ sets $A_n$.

Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \mu (A_n) \leq K \mu \left ( \cup_{n=1}^{+\infty} A_n \right ).$$

Could you give me some hints how I could show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denoting by 
$$
\mathbf1_{B}(x)=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if }x\in B,\\
0&\text{if }x\notin B,
\end{cases}
$$
for any measurable set $B\subset X$, the following inequality holds
$$
\sum_{n\ge1}\mathbf1_{A_n}\le K\mathbf1_{\left\{\bigcup_{n\ge1}A_n\right\}}
$$
(the left hand side is zero if $x\notin\bigcup_nA_n$ and is less than $K$ by hypothesis).
Integrating the inequality with respect to $\mu$ yields the required result.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For every $I$ subset of the index set for $(A_n)$  consider the set 
$$\mathcal{A}_I = (\cap_{n\in I } A_n) \cap (\cap_{n \in \mathbb{N} \backslash I} A_n')$$

Then $(\mathcal{A}_I)_{|I| \le k}$ form a partition of $\cup A_n$. One verifies that

$$\sum \mu(A_n) = \sum |I| \mu (\mathcal{A}_I) \le k \cdot \sum \mu(\mathcal{A}_I) = k \cdot \mu(\cup_n A_n)$$

Indeed, for all $n$, the sets $(\mathcal{A}_I)_{n \in I}$ form a partition of $A_n$, .

Comment: Thank you very much!!! :-)