# Show that $m(A)\leq \frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=1}^\infty m(E_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For each $n\in \Bbb N$ let $E_n\subseteq R$ be a measurable set. Fix $k\in\Bbb N$, and let $A$ be the set of all $x\in\Bbb R$ that belong to at least $k$ of the $E_n's$

(a) Show that $A$ is measurable

(b) Show that $m(A)\leq \frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=1}^\infty m(E_n)$

---

**Attempt**. Let $A_k$ be the set of all $x\in\Bbb R$ that belong to exactly $k$ of the $E_n$'s. Then $A=\sqcup_{i=k}^\infty A_i$. Note that for each $i\in\Bbb N$, the set $A_i$ is the intersection of $i$ sets from the sequence $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, so since it is a countable intersection of some measurable sets, it is measurable. Since A is a countable union of measurable sets, $A$ is measurable. This proves (a).

For part (b), we have $m(A)=m(\sqcup_{i=k}^\infty A_i)\leq \mu(\sqcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i)=\mu(\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n)$. I would be glad if someone could help to conclude that $m(A)\leq \frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=1}^\infty m(E_n)$. Thanks!

Comment: $A_k$ is a little more complex than that.  For instance, $A_2 = (E_1 \cap E_2) \cup (E_1 \cap E_3) \cup \dots \cup (E_2 \cap E_3) \cup (E_2 \cap E_4) \cup \dots$.  Yet still it is indeed measurable, being a countable union of finite intersections of the $E_n$.

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141320/proving-sum-n-1-infty-mu-a-n-leq-k-mu-left-cup-n-1-infty?rq=1